# how to blink an image in matlab gui

Tags: matlab

I have tried giving this in  axes handle. If I try this in normal window, the figure starts to appear and disappear. However, in gui the neither the image nor the figure blinks.

```
for i = 1:1:10
imshow('supriya.jpg','Parent',handles.axes1);    
drawnow();
pause(0.1);        
end
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you use the for-loop? Do you really want to have 10 copies of the image open?

Comment: What do you mean by blink?

Comment: I think it's just an artifact of how `imshow` clears and then redraws the figure. You can always try something like `clf(); drawnow(); imshow('supriya.jpg','Parent',handles.axes1);`. I don't know if that's what you're looking for, but it might help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by 'blink' you mean display/don't display the image rapidly.

A simple way is to retrieve the handle of the image object you are displaying, then you can switch its visibility on and off at the time interval of your choice.

Something like that should get you started:

```
handles.axes1 = axes ;
handles.image = imshow('supriya.jpg','Parent',handles.axes1);    
for i = 1:1:10
   set( handles.image , 'Visible','off')
   pause(0.1);        
   set( handles.image , 'Visible','on')
   pause(0.1);        
end
```